# Validate PCRE in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I am using Python and I need to check that a string is a valid PCRE regex.

Is this possible using `re`?

If not, is it possible with an external Python library?

I know how to check whether something is a valid Python regex:

```
try:
    a = re.compile(str)
except re.error:
    # fail
```

But not how to check for PCRE.

Comment: Please be a little more specific ...

Comment: I assume there are some strings that are valid Python regexes, but not valid PCRE regexes. These strings will compile correctly with `re.compile`, but when I pass them to my Mongo db (which expects a PCRE regex) will cause it to fail. I'd like to catch these in my Python app before causing a Mongo error. Is there a way to do this in Python? (Obviously, I can handle the Mongo error separately, but for various reasons it would be much easier to do the validation in Python.)

Comment: Just catch the error. You will end up writing a parser if you want to validate PCRE regex yourself. Or there is the option of using a Python wrapper https://github.com/awahlig/python-pcre and try to compile it beforehand.

Comment: the language of regular expressions is not regular, so you can't write a regular expression to check it.

Comment: You might want to just use a python pcre library like [this one](https://github.com/awahlig/python-pcre).